# Go conditional pointer value

Tags: go, pointers

I have a couple of structs in a program. I have a pointer that should conditionally point to one of these structs. Here is a short non-functioning example:

```golang
type Struct1 struct {
    name string
}
type Struct2 struct {
    name string
}

func main() {
    var outputDevice
    switch inputValue {
        case "one":
            outputDevice = &Struct1{name: "name"}
        case "two":
            outputDevice = &struct2{name: "name"}
    }
}
```

Note, both of the structs have a common interface:

```golang
type Output interface {
    Print() error
}
```

Any ideas about how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what interfaces are for.

If your two types already share a common interface, than make your variable of the interface type:

```
var outputDevice Output
```

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks for your help. I had a feeling that it was something like this but was trying to create a pointer to the interface for some reason.